# Type annotation of return value of a function which returns numpy single value

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

If I want to add type annotation to the return value of the following function, how should I?

```py
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x: np.ndarray):
    return x.sum()
```

The type of return value of the function vary:

- `np.int8` if `x.dtype` is `dtype('int8')`
- `np.int16` if `x.dtype` is `dtype('int16')`
- `np.int32` if `x.dtype` is `dtype('int32')`
- `np.float16` if `x.dtype` is `dtype('float16')`
- `np.float32` if `x.dtype` is `dtype('float32')`
  ... etc.

Of cause I want to avoid using `-> Any`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NDArray from the numpy typing module and define a TypeVar that is bound to numpy scalar types. This bound type you can pass to the NDArray type and annotate the return type of your function with that same type.

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import TypeVar
from numpy.typing import NDArray

ScalarType = TypeVar("ScalarType", bound=np.generic, covariant=True)

def myfunc(x: NDArray[ScalarType]) -> ScalarType:
    return x.sum()
```